# Auto positioning controls (without TableLayoutPanel)

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

My problem is in the picture:

[image: position]

How can i position automatically the next control (textbox in this sample), without a TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: Just keep a Y variable that keeps track of the position of the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want the `TextBox` move left/right based on the width of `Label`?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int gap1 = textBox1.Left - label1.Right;
    label1.AutoSize = true;
    label1.Text = "long long long long long long long long";
    textBox1.Left = label1.Right + gap1;

    int gap2 = textBox1.Left - label1.Right;
    label2.AutoSize = true;
    label2.Text = "s";
    textBox2.Left = label2.Right + gap2;
}
```

You firstly record the gap between the `TextBox` and `Label`, then set the `AutoSize` to `true`, followed by setting the new content of `Label`, finally you can move the `TextBox` accordingly.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

If you need to align multiple `TextBox`, or the width of `TextBox` as well, it would be more complicated, but you can follow the similar logic.

However, you have to write your own code but not doable in the Design view, as the `Anchor` of control is to the parent container but not the sibling control. Well, in `Xcode` on Mac you could do this, but AFAIK `Visual Studio` does not have this feature out of the box.

Comment: "Do you mean you want the TextBox move left/right based on the width of Label?" Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of using a **counter** to track the number of controls created and compute the proper Y position:

```
private int counter = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    int y = counter * 25;

    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "Label " + counter.ToString();
    lbl.Location = new Point(5, y);

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Location = new Point(lbl.Bounds.Right + 5, y);
    this.Controls.Add(lbl);
    this.Controls.Add(tb);
}
```